# Korean characters showing up as random symbols in internet explorer, served by Apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, internet-explorer

I am hosting a webpage on an Apache server on  CentOS 8 computer, which contains English as well as Korean characters. The characters render correctly in Chrome and in Edge, but don't do so in Internet explorer. This is what it looks like:

[image]

and this what it should look like:

[image]

`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` is commented as shown below:

```
#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

The html file  is defined as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../../meta/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>
<body>
```

So why aren't the Korean characters rendering properly on internet explorer?

Adding <meta ...> as explaied in the answer solved this problem:

```
<html>
<head>
        <link href="../meta/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8">
        <meta charset="EUC-KR">
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your posted information shows, you have not defined the charset anywhere – neither in the HTTP headers (via Apache) nor in the HTML file itself. (The HTML file *only* specifies a charset for the linked CSS stylesheet – but not for the HTML itself!)

As a result web browsers are [forced to guess](https://hsivonen.fi/chardetng/) which charset is most likely to be in use (based on statistical analysis), and different browsers use different algorithms – often based on the operating system's locale and/or the website's domain. So if you're using English Windows, then browsers will try to guess English or European encodings first.

To avoid this, you will need to add a charset declaration inside `<head>`. Your example image looks like it was originally EUC-KR (but misdetected as Windows-1252), so add a tag like this:

```
<meta charset="EUC-KR">
```

Another very common encoding for international webpages is `UTF-8`.

Note that browsers may require the charset declaration to be within the first 1 kB of the file, so it's always best to place it as close to the top of <head> as you can.

---

For compatibility with very old browsers, there's also the long version:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
```

Comment: Should the long version be used instead or along with the short version?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski may be long version is not necessary, I just added the short version (edited into the question) and it works. I probably don't need to support very old browsers so I didn't use the longer one

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: AFAIK, one is enough – I don't think I have seen any browsers _not_ support the long version, nor heard any plans to remove support for it... On the other hand, the short version is also supported [practically everywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Browser_compatibility) as well. (By "very old" I meant something from Windows 98 era, I guess.)

Comment: Are there any other encodings besides "EUC-KR" to display Korean? I found one particular html file that looks normal on notepad++, but the korean characters are messed up in chrome as well as IE. The Korean characters in this case are text between the <a href>..</a> tags, if that makes any difference. Non of the Korean characters in the previous cases were hyperlinks

Comment: Adding <meta charset="EUC-KR"> to this html file gives me a mixture of Chinese characters and Korean gibberish, and not adding it gives me the 'normal' sort of gibberish (things like /?. and accented English characters)

Comment: There is Unicode UTF-8 (the current de facto standard for web) and there probably are some old encodings as well, but I'm not sure which ones. Possibly iso-2022-kr? (Do you have a screenshot of both the correct and wrong displays?) Or just check Notepad++'s encoding menu to see which encoding it's currently using to show the file, then look up the official HTML name for it.

Comment: Notepad++ has "Encode in UTF-8" selected under Encoding

Comment: Then just add <meta charset="UTF-8"> and see if that works

Comment: I also just noticed Chrome gives me the option of translating this page from Vietnamese to English, for some reason

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> worked. Thanks a lot!!